# Quelle terminaison à « Qui m’aurait diτ » ?

Tags: accord, participe-passé, auxiliaires

Comment orthographie-t-on « Qui m’aurait di**τ** » ?

À la place du tau, dois-je mettre un *s* ?
Normalement, le participe s’accorde avec le COD lorsque ce dernier vient avant l’auxiliaire, ce qui est notre cas.

Or, ici, le COD est *moi*. Mais comment accorder le participe passé avec *moi* ? Si j’y met la terminaison de la première personne, cela supposerait que *moi* est le sujet de la phrase, sauf qu’il en est le COD.

Donc, comment accorder ce participe passé ?

Comment: One ne dit pas tau en français; on dit la letter t. Pourquoi utiliser une lettre grecque?

Comment: @Lambie La lettre **τ** se dit bien [tau](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tau) en français. Fauve a utilisé cette lettre pour représenter graphiquement son hésitation entre *T* et *S*. C'est assez évident.

Comment: @jlliagre La lettre tau se dit pareil en anglais, c'est grecque. Autre chose? Laisse-moi poser une question sans inter-diction  (c'est du latin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Qui m'aurait **dit**.

***Me*** est ici un complément d'objet indirect (aurait dit **à** qui ? **à** moi).

Dans l'hypothèse un peu tirée par les cheveux où ***me*** serait un complément d'objet direct, le participe passé se serait accordé avec ***me***, donc soit au masculin (***dit***), soit au féminin, (***dite***).

En aucun cas, on ne peut avoir *<s>aurait **dis**</s>*.